# How to open ftp link from website in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, browser, windows-explorer, development

So, i have link on ftp in my page. When user click on this link he's relocate on ftp which open in browser. Is it possible to create behavior such as opening ftp links in Windows Explorer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make shortcut to ftp site open in windows explorer not IE](http://superuser.com/questions/166469/how-to-make-shortcut-to-ftp-site-open-in-windows-explorer-not-ie)

Comment: it's not about shortcuts it's about opening ftp after click on link in browser. But idea is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could script it via a batch file and the command line FTP client, but you will need a client. Regular windows explorer doesn't have a way to connect to an FTP site by itself.

Comment: in other words browser can't redirect you to ftp in windows explorer by default. Ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start Menu->Computer
2. On the left pane: right-click computer-> add network location
3. Follow the wizard and type in your ftp location (ftp://yourusername:password@yourftpsite.com)
4. Right click the network location and send to your desktop as shortcut.

Comment: thnx for advice but my question not about this method.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: no problem) thank you. it looks like that it's impossible)