# When visiting an ftp site in the file explorer on Windows 10, it opens the site in the Web Browser

Tags: windows-explorer, ftp

What is the setting that would change this behavior so that the ftp site opens in the file explorer itself? For example, if I were to visit ftp://ftp.gnu.org/, I want it to show the file structure in the file explorer and not open the browser at all.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/166469/how-to-make-shortcut-to-ftp-site-open-in-windows-explorer-not-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/217888/how-to-install-and-use-ftp-folders

The gist of it is:

1. Open the Control Panel, and then double-click Internet Options.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Under Browsing, click the Use Web Based FTP or Enable Folder View for FTP sites check box to select it.

Answer (score 3):

I too had issues with this, however, you can by-pass it by adding the FTP site as a Network Location.

So from Windows 10 File Explorer:

- in the navigation pane, click on ***This PC***
- In the ***Computer*** Toolbar select ***Add a network location***
- {Next}{Next} in the ***Internet or Network address:*** enter the FTP address in the form:

  ```
  ftp://[[username]:[Password]]@FTPServerName
  e.g   ftp://firstlast:password@ftp.gnu.org
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy solution that worked for me.

1. Copy the ftp address using <kbd>Control+C</kbd>
2. Open File Explorer and copy the address into the address bar using <kbd>Control+V</kbd>

Took me 20 minutes to figure this one out.  Hope it saves you some time.

Comment: This doens't answer the question. Of course the address must be typed in or copied and pasted with Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, otherwise how do you think the OP browse that address?

Comment: Thank you. This helped me.